# django-import-export export is slow when there is foreign key

Tags: django, django-import-export

when there is foreign key in model, exporting is very slow, when I exclude the foreign there is no problem, it starts to download quickly. What might be the issue here? Thanks!

My code is like,

resources.py

```
class InvoiceResource(resources.ModelResource):
  class Meta:
      model = Invoices
```

views.py

```
def export_invoice(request):
  person_resource = InvoiceResource()
  dataset = person_resource.export()
  response = HttpResponse(dataset.xlsx, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="invoices.xlsx"'
  return response
```

models.py

```
class Invoices(models.Model):
   store_code = models.ForeignKey(MasterData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='Store Code', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Store Code')
   erp_id = models.CharField(db_column='ERP ID', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='ERP ID')
   store_name = models.CharField(db_column='Store Name', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Store Name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use select_related

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    fk = models.Foreingkey(ModelB)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
```

if you use:

```
a_objects = ModelA.objects.all()

for obj in a_objects:
    fk = obj.fk
```

every object need query to database

but if you use

```
a_objects = ModelA.objects.all().select_related('fk')

for obj in a_objects:
    fk = obj.fk
```

in this case only one query to database.

For more information go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/

```
class InvoiceResource(resources.ModelResource):

  def get_queryset(self):
      return super().get_queryset().select_related('store_code')
  class Meta:
      model = Invoices
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked both queries and yes, second one is way more faster, however how can I implement that to the resource.export() command? or should I do something directly in resources.py file?

Comment: I have added, what you should do with resources

Comment: I tried but there is no change, it still takes long time to export